# UTF-8 "inconsistency" when storing unicode key/values from CSV file into dict

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode

I always get very confused when dealing with Unicode and UTF-8 characters and encodings in Python. There's probably a simple explanation to what I'm going to detail below, but, so far, I can't wrap my head around it.

Let's say I have a very very simple `.csv` file that contains non-ascii characters:

`tildes.csv`:

```
Año,Valor
2001,Café
2002,León
```

I want to read that file using a [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) object and store its key/values as `unicode` strings, with tildes and such handled properly (unescaped) in a python dict. I've seen Tornado and Django handling unicode key/value sets properly, so I said to myself *Yep, I can do that too!!*... But nopes... it looks like I can't.

```
import csv

with open('tildes.csv', 'r') as csv_f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_f)
    for dct in reader:
        print "dct (original): %s" % dct
        for k, v in dct.items():
            print '%s: %s' % (unicode(k, 'utf-8'), unicode(v, 'utf-8'))
        utf_dct = dict((unicode(k, 'utf-8'), unicode(v, 'utf-8')) \
                  for k, v in dct.items())
        print utf_dct
```

So, I thought: *Ok, I read a `dict` from the file (Its keys being `Año` and `Valor`) which will be loaded **ascii** with escaped characters, but then I can encode those into unicode values and use them as keys...* Wrong!

This is what I see when I run the code above:

```
dct (original): {'A\xc3\xb1o': '2001', 'Valor': 'Caf\xc3\xa9'}
Año: 2001
Valor: Café
{u'A\xf1o': u'2001', u'Valor': u'Caf\xe9'}
dct (original): {'A\xc3\xb1o': '2002', 'Valor': 'Le\xc3\xb3n'}
Año: 2002
Valor: León
{u'A\xf1o': u'2002', u'Valor': u'Le\xf3n'}
```

So the first line shows the dictionary 'as it is' (escaped). Good, nothing odd here. Then I `print` all the key/values parsed to unicode. It shows the characters the way I want it. Good too. But then, using the exact same instruction I used to re-encode the strings when I printed them, I try to create a `dict` (the `utf_dct` variable) and when I print it, I get the values escaped again.

---

**EDIT 1**:

Actually, I don't think I even need a csv file to show what I mean. I just tried this in my console:

```
>>> print "Año"
Año                      # Yeey!! There's hope!
>>> print {"Año": 2001}
{'A\xc3\xb1o': 2001}     # 2 chars --> Ascii, I think I get this part 
>>> print {u"Año": 2001}
{u'A\xf1o': 2001}        # What happened here? 
                         # Why am I seeing the 0x00F1 UTF-8 code 
                         # from the Latin-1 Supplement (wiki:
                         # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block)
                         # instead of an ñ?
```

Why can't I just print a dict showing `{u'Año': 2001}`? My terminal clearly accepts it. What's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print the string itself, it is printed "nicely", using its `str()` representation.  When you print a dictionary, its contents are printed using their `repr()` representation, which always escapes.  The contents of the string are the same in both cases, it's just that Python displays them differently.  It is the same reason that no quote marks are printed around `Año` in the first case, but quote marks are printed around `'A\xc3\xb1o'` in the second case.  It's just two different display formats.

Here is an even simpler example that may help illustrate the situation:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name('\u00f1') # 00F1 is unicode code point for this character
'LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE'
>>> print(str(u'\u00f1')) # str() gives a displayable character
ñ
>>> print repr(u'\u00f1') # repr() gives an escaped representation
u'\xf1'
>>> print repr(str(u'\u00f1')) # repr() of the str() shows the two characters in the UTF-8 encoding -- this is what happens when showing a dict
'\xc3\xb1'
>>> len(str(u'\u00f1')) # the str() is two bytes long (UTF-8 encoded)
2
>>> len(repr(u'\u00f1')) # the repr() is 7 bytes long (`u`, `'`, `\`, `x`, `f`, `1`, `'`)
7
```

There is a [related bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue2630) suggesting to change this behavior so that `repr` doesn't escape non-ASCII characters.  According to that bug report, this change was made in Python 3, so tools that you have seen doing this may be using Python 3.

It's also possible for individual tools to display anything however they like.  A tool doesn't have to just call `str(someDict)` and display the result; if it wants, it can "manually" call `str` on the contents of the dict instead and build up its own displayable version from that.

Comment: That makes sense... But how is it possible that some tools show a "proper" `{Año: 2001}`? I could swear I've seen that happening. Do you think those are not an actual Python `dict` (but some kind of derived class) and they overwrote the `__repr__` method in said class? (sorry, I know the most accurate answer to this comment would be *Dude... depends on what tool you're talking about* Is more... Do you know if overwriting `__repr__` is a common practice?

Comment: @BorrajaX: I added some more info to my answer.  It's possible that those tools don't just display the `str` of the object, but have their own display routine that calls `str` on the contents instead of `repr`.  But yes, it would depend what tool you're talking about.